# Как ограничить запросы к suggest-maps.yandex.ru/suggest-geo городом или страной

Tags: javascript, yandex-maps-api, yandex-geocoding-api

У меня есть форма с инпутом, при вводе текста в которую в яндекс улетают запросы вида `Request URL: https://suggest-maps.yandex.ru/suggest-geo?callback=&apikey=&v=5&search_type=tp&part=2&lang=ru_RU&n=5&origin=jsapi2Geocoder&bbox=-180%2C-90%2C180%2C90` в итоге по поиску "средняя" находится населённый пункт в Сомали...

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Как можно ограничить выборку по стране, а в идеале по городу?

Инпут создаю вот так `new ymaps.SuggestView('search-form')`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Разобрался :) Нужно сделать вот так

```
let sv = new ymaps.SuggestView('search-form', {
    boundedBy: myMap.getBounds()
});
```

Где `MyMap` - это

```
myMap = new ymaps.Map("ya-map", {
                center: yourCenter,
                zoom: 5,
                controls: ['zoomControl']
            }
```

Answer (score 1):

Я реализовал это так:

```js
    var locality = 'Чеченская Республика';
    var state = 'Грозный';

    var suggestView = new ymaps.SuggestView('address', {
    provider: {
    suggest: (function(request, options) {
              return ymaps.suggest(locality+", "+state+", "+request)
              })
    }});
```

И весь поиск у меня выполняется по Грозному.

Comment: А `locality` у вас откуда приходит?